# Error - b'Error in sasl_client_start (-4) SASL(-4): no mechanism available: Unable to find a callback: 2'

Tags: python, python-3.x, hive

I am trying to connect to HIVE via Python (Jupyter Notebooks). I have installed all the necessary packages for connecting HIVE using Python -

```
sasl                      0.2.1            py37h8a4fda4_1
thrift                    0.13.0                   pypi_0    pypi
thrift-sasl               0.3.0                    pypi_0    pypi
pyhive                    0.6.1                    pypi_0    pypi

from pyhive import hive
conn = hive.Connection(host="xxxxxxx", port=xxxxx, username="xxxxxxxx")
```

But unable to connect as it's throwing error: `TTransportException: Could not start SASL: b'Error in sasl_client_start (-4) SASL(-4): no mechanism available: Unable to find a callback: 2'`.

Am I missing anything? How do I connect?

Comment: +1: PS C:\tools> python .\run.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".\run.py", line 12, in <module>
    cursor = hive.connect(host=HIVE_HOST, port=HIVE_PORT,  Could not start SASL: b'Error in sasl_client_start (-4) SASL(-4): no mechanism available: Unable to find a callback: 2'echanism available: Unable to find a callback: 2'

Answer (score 1):

On the Windows platform, you need to add to win reestr the path to your C:\PyProj\MyProj\venv\Lib\site-packages\sasl\sasl2 directory. In the win command line:
C:\Windows\system32>REG ADD "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Carnegie Mellon\Project Cyrus\SASL Library" /v SearchPath /t REG_SZ /d "C:\PyProj\MyProj\venv\Lib\site-packages\sasl\sasl2"

Answer (score 0):

You can try installing the following packages:

```
yum install cyrus-sasl-plain  cyrus-sasl-devel  cyrus-sasl-gssapi
```

This worked for me.